# How to set AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer as background in SKScene in Sprite Kit Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation, augmented-reality

So I'm trying to build an augmented reality game with Sprite kit in swift 3. I am able to set the video for my camera as a background but it appears over my nodes. Basically, the nodes are underneath the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. How can I make my nodes appear over the background (sort of similar to Pokémon go)? I have even tried to change the zPosition but this doesn't work. This is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
class GameScene: SKScene {
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    isPaused = false
    addPlayer()

    scene?.backgroundColor = .clear
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
    } catch {
        return
    }
    captureSession.startRunning()
    if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    } else {
        return
    }


    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    captureSession.startRunning() 
 }
```